# How to call swap() algorithm on std::list elements?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to swap the 2nd and 4th elements in a list, but I can't figure out how to do this. I tried to use vector notation, but it didn't work.

```
list<int> a1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
swap(a1[1], a1[3]);
```

Comment: `iter_swap(a1.begin(),next(a1.begin(),2))`

Answer (score 5):

A `std::list` doesn't provide random access indexing, like a `std::vector` or an array does. You need to use iterators instead, eg:

```
auto first_node = a1.begin();
auto second_node = std::next(first_node);
auto fourth_node = std::next(first_node, 3);

std::swap(*second_node, *fourth_node);
```